# Dimple - adding custom shapes to a responsive chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, responsive-design, dimple.js

I'm coding a dimple based bubble chart, which for some z-values removes a bubble and draws a big red X instead, which is an svg path created by line interpolation like this:

```
var points = [{"x":x-edgeSize,"y":y+edgeSize},
                          {"x":x,"y":y},
                          {"x":x+edgeSize,"y":y-edgeSize},
                          {"x":x,"y":y},
                          {"x":x-edgeSize,"y":y-edgeSize},
                          {"x":x,"y":y},
                          {"x":x+edgeSize,"y":y+edgeSize},
                          {"x":x,"y":y}];
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                .interpolate("linear");
var path = graphSelection.append("path").attr("d",lineFunction(points))
                    .attr("stroke",color)
                    .attr("stroke-width",lineWidth);
```

Now, I want it to be responsive and I followed dimple's example for responsive charts:
[Dimple - Responsive sizing](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_responsive_sizing) and now all the sizes and bounds are by % and I'm calling draw on resize:

```
this.chart.draw(this.delay,true);
```

The problem is that the red Xs don't move by themselves, obviously.

So I tried to move it independently on resize, but I don't know the right coordinates until the transition ends - which makes it a 2 step transition.

Will adding the X-path to series.shapes help? will it move along with the other bubbles?

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Thanks